# Json-server mocking API instead of calls

Tags: node.js, mocking, backend, nestjs, json-server

I'm making an API using NestJS (NodeJS) and in order to run it in local enviromment without having all external APIs running, i want to mock the calls to external APIs while my API running.

In order to do this, I choose Json-server to do it, Here is the code:

mockserver.ts:

```js
export async function bootstrap() {
  const app = create();
  app.use(
    defaults({
      logger: true,
      static: 'static',
    }),
    router(dbJSON),
    jsonServer.rewriter(routesJSON),
  );

  app.use('/api', router);
}
```

i tried also :

```js
export async function bootstrap() {
  const app = create();
  app.use(
    defaults({
      logger: true,
      static: 'static',
    }),
    router(db),
    jsonServer.rewriter(routesJSON),
  );

  app.use('/api', router);
  const port = process.env.mockPort ?? 8080;
  app.listen(port);
```

main.ts :

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule)

  const mocks = await import('../mocks/server');
  app.use(await mocks.bootstrap(null));

  await app.listen(DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, DEFAULT_HOST);
}
```

However, instead of mocking the calls to external APIs using the db and the routes given to Json-server, my API itself was mocked.

Any ideas on how can I mock an API calls to external API while running? or how to make json-server mock call httpService calls only instead of the API itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this before, but I think you either need to configure the existing HttpModule to sometimes forward calls or wrap HttpModule with a new module that decides whether or not to forward requests to the real server or mock server.

You can give `HttpModule` a configuration via [register](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module#configuration). See the async configuration if you want to inject `ConfigService` to configure it based off of an environment variable that determines if you're local or not. The config object is an [Axios request config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config). However, I don't see a way to redirect requests via config.

`HttpModule` uses `axios`, so another option would be [axios interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors). In a request interceptor, you could have it only override `config.url` when running locally. To set up interceptors at the beginning of the app, you could create a module `MyHttpModule` that injects `HttpService`, and in an `onModuleInit`, get a reference to the axios instance and set the interceptors. Check out [this example](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events#lifecycle-events-1) I found.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I actually made it work using interceptors, to be more precise for future reference; I used HttpModule as an interceptor. First I check if it is running in the right environment for the mocks, if yes I run the interceptor. The interceptor will use ```httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use``` to intercept and change URL to the mock's server URL.